# Azure Pipelines - Output from Python Script not being saved to Artifact

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm new to Azure DevOps; I have a pipeline that runs a python script, which scrapes some text from some files and saves it as a dictionary in a json file. I am trying to publish the json file as a pipeline artifact (so that I can actually access it), but whenever I trigger the pipeline, the json file is empty.

Here is the YAML configuration:

```
stages:
- stage: scrape_text
  jobs:
    - job: run_script
      displayName: 'Scrape text'
      steps:
        - task: PythonScript@0
          displayName: 'Run scraper script'
          inputs:
            scriptSource: 'filePath'
            scriptPath: 'path/to/scraper.py'
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
          inputs:
            targetPath: 'path/to/text.json'
            artifactName: 'text_artifact'
            publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

I'm certain that the python script runs successfully (after saving the json file, it successfully reads and prints out its contents; running the script locally also gives me the desired output). The artifact is also built successfully, but it's completely empty. When checking the logs, I see a message saying 'Uploaded 0 out of 180 bytes'.

Is there something I'm not understanding about how Azure Pipelines work?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned, "python script, which scrapes some text from some files and saves it as a **dictionary** in a json file". So you should provide the path to that directory like this: `targetPath: 'path/to/dir/text.json'` . You are probably providing a wrong path.Let me know if you have any Questions.